# Ansible fail module does not work due to runtime error

Tags: ansible, runtime-error

I have a playbook with a task that `greps` for a string in a file. If the string is found the block should fail. However, inside the rescue fail module it fails to print the message and errors:

Here is my playbook:

```
---

- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - block:
      - name: "Search for IP"
        command: "grep -w {{ source_host }} {{ playbook_dir }}/allhost.hosts"
        register: command_result
        failed_when: command_result.rc == 0


     rescue:
      - name: Print custom conditional debug message
        fail:
          msg: >-
            {{
              command_result.rc == 0 |
              ternary(
                "This IP On-Boarded.",
                "The DB is not reachable."
              )
            }}
```

I tried changing

```
command_result.rc == 0 |
```

To

```
command_result.stdout is search ( source_host ) |
```

But that too did not help.

Considering `command_result.rc = 0;` I was expecting "This IP is On-Boarded." to be printed however it does not. Can you let me know what is the issue with my playbook?

Output:

```
TASK [Search for IP] *****************************
[1;30mtask path: /tmp/filegaurd.yml:20[0m
[0;34mUsing module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py[0m
[0;34mPipelining is enabled.[0m
[0;34m<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: user1[0m
[0;34m<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 && sleep 0'[0m
[0;31mfatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {[0m
[0;31m    "changed": true, [0m
[0;31m    "cmd": [[0m
[0;31m        "grep", [0m
[0;31m        "-w", [0m
[0;31m        "10.9.9.91", [0m
[0;31m        "/tmp/allhost.hosts"[0m
[0;31m    ], [0m
[0;31m    "delta": "0:00:00.096103", [0m
[0;31m    "end": "2020-03-13 07:25:43.705938", [0m
[0;31m    "failed_when_result": true, [0m
[0;31m    "invocation": {[0m
[0;31m        "module_args": {[0m
[0;31m            "_raw_params": "grep -w 10.9.9.91 /tmp/allhost.hosts", [0m
[0;31m            "_uses_shell": false, [0m
[0;31m            "argv": null, [0m
[0;31m            "chdir": null, [0m
[0;31m            "creates": null, [0m
[0;31m            "executable": null, [0m
[0;31m            "removes": null, [0m
[0;31m            "stdin": null, [0m
[0;31m            "stdin_add_newline": true, [0m
[0;31m            "strip_empty_ends": true, [0m
[0;31m            "warn": true[0m
[0;31m        }[0m
[0;31m    }, [0m
[0;31m    "rc": 0, [0m
[0;31m    "start": "2020-03-13 07:25:43.609835", [0m
[0;31m    "stderr": "", [0m
[0;31m    "stderr_lines": [], [0m
[0;31m    "stdout": "10.9.9.91 USERID=user1 files_list=/tmp/winstone4603745991442278706.jar,/tmp/winstone5835113081224811756.jar", [0m
[0;31m    "stdout_lines": [[0m
[0;31m        "10.9.9.91 USERID=user1 files_list=/tmp/winstone460.jar,/tmp/winstone56.jar"[0m
[0;31m    ][0m
[0;31m}[0m


TASK [Print custom conditional debug message] **********************************
[1;30mtask path: /tmp/file.yml:28[0m
[0;31mfatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {[0m
[0;31m    "changed": false, [0m
[0;31m    "msg": "False "[0m
[0;31m}[0m


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
[0;31mlocalhost[0m                  : [0;32mok=1   [0m changed=0    unreachable=0    [0;31mfailed=1   [0m skipped=0    [0;32mrescued=1   [0m ignored=0
```

Comment: what does `action == "onboard"` mean?

Comment: It's just a variable which matches condition. It cab be ignored . Will remove it from original post

Comment: Ok si basically you tell ansible that when you have a rc 0 your task is failed. I think what you meant is the opposite? `failed_when: command_result.rc != 0`

Comment: I wish to fail when command_result == 0. Please understand that the issue with the `fail` module inside `rescue`. You should not be concerned of the `block` as it works fine as evident from the output shared

Comment: Thanks for clarification, indeed I didn't understand that. I think I the error might come from the filter being more associative than == so what's get evaluated would be `command_result.rc == (0 | ternary("This IP On-Boarded.", "The DB is not reachable."))` which is always false. Can you try `(command_result.rc == 0) | ternary("This IP On-Boarded.", "The DB is not reachable.")` instead?

Comment: @rolf82 I tried your suggestion and put round brackets around `(command_result.rc == 0)` but now I get ` Syntax Error while loading YAML. The offending line appears to be: ternary ( ^ here`

Comment: can you try with ternary on the same line as the test? I tried `{{ (test_var == 0) | ternary('ok', 'ko') }}` which works, but if I go to newline after `|` then I've got the syntax error.

Comment: Works please share the suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jinja filter operator `|` being more associative than `==`, what is actually evaluated is that:

```
command_result.rc == (0 | ternary("This IP On-Boarded.", "The DB is not reachable."))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
command_result.rc == "The DB is not reachable."
```

which always equals to `False`, that's why you've got the output `"msg": "False "`.
To solve this problem you have to use parentheses around the test:

```
(command_result.rc == 0) | ternary("This IP On-Boarded.", "The DB is not reachable.")
```

Note that the whole filter should be on the same line.